# cmake add_library, followed by install library destination

Tags: cmake

I am trying to run cmake to generate makefiles. In the minimum working example, I have three files and 1 build directory.

File 1 is CMakeLists.txt, containing exactly:

```
add_library (MathFunctions SHARED mysqrt.cxx)
install (TARGETS MathFunctions LIBRARY DESTINATION lib)
```

File 2 is MathFunctions.h containing the function prototype, function relates to mysqrt.cxx.

File 3 is mysqrt.cxx containing include statement and a function definition.

When I create a build sub-directory and run "cmake ..", I am getting

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (install):
  install Library TARGETS given no DESTINATION!
```

Isn't my add_library, then install statement grammar correct? If I remove both SHARED and LIBRARY, cmake builds without errors.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is likely down to you running this on what CMake calls a "DLL platform" and how CMake classifies a shared library on such a platform.

From the docs for [`install`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/install.html):

> For DLL platforms the DLL part of a shared library is treated as a `RUNTIME` target and the corresponding import library is treated as an `ARCHIVE` target. All Windows-based systems including Cygwin are DLL platforms.

So, try changing your command to something like:

```
install (TARGETS MathFunctions
         ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib
         LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
         RUNTIME DESTINATION bin)
```

Comment: Hello Fraser, do you think you could please explain what is the difference between ARCHIVE / LIBRARY / RUNTIME? It is not really clear to me from the documentation