# Bcrypt C++ library

Tags: c++, windows, cmake

So I found this library [link here](https://github.com/trusch/libbcrypt). But when I configure it on windows i get this error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:41 (install):
install Library TARGETS given no DESTINATION!
```

And I don't know if this is a computer specific error cause I didn't find an answer to it in a long session of googling. I also opened the issue on the github but maybe I'll post here to see if someone can help me. I'm using Windows 10 64-bit- The Generator is Visual Studio 15 2017.

Comment: So the CMakeLists.txt there is 51 lines long. It is not impossible to adapt it or to at least to remove the broken functionality that blocks you. What do you think? Issue on github will unlikely help, as it is clearly an abandoned hobby/student project. The last commit is 2 years ago, and there are total of 7  commits, all from 1 guy. See the problem? However it is always nice to do some research and to try to fix the problem before asking or god save, opening an issue. If you'll manage to fix it, you can fork the repository and share the fix with everybody. That's the open-source way.

Comment: I am completely clueless when it comes to cmake. So I was hoping if there was a simple fix and if anybody would know it. I will find a workaround so I don't have to use this library but it was worth a try

Comment: Have you checked [CMakeLists.txt, line 41](https://github.com/trusch/libbcrypt/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L41) as cmake suggested  to you? Is it really that complicated?

Comment: If I set the directory to somewhere on my pc it gives me the same error

Comment: That's what Google recommended me: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22278381/cmake-add-library-followed-by-install-library-destination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22278381/cmake-add-library-followed-by-install-library-destination)

Comment: You see, the author of the library you've chosen has only setup the build for Unix-like OS, likely his own OS. It is clear, because there are hardcoded Linux paths and .deb CPack there. Few things to consider: is it a good enough library? Do you really need this "wrapper"? If yes, do you really need the failing installation step of the build? May be you can just get rid of it? In fact, can you get rid of that bad CMake file whatsoever and just take all the 6 (!) source files that library consists of and to copy them into your project?

Comment: Yeah maybe I'll try that

Answer (score -2):

I just copied the files to my project